# Filtered and excluded results in same query

Tags: sql, django

I am working on a use case, such that I need to filter a query set , perform a function on the results and then perform the same function on the rest of the query set.

```
# Example (since everybody is having quizzes these days)
query_set = Quiz.objects.filter()
todays_quizzes = query_set.filter(created__startswith=today)
not_todays_quizzes = query_set.exclude(created__starswith=today)
perform_function(todays_quizzes)
perform_function(not_todays_quizzes)
```

What I would like to know is, is there a better way to get `not_todays_quizzes` rather than having to perform almost the same query again but with just the opposite condition. i.e can I get both results in one query. Is it even possible at sql level?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Wouldn't the set of quizzes that have or haven't been created today consist of all the quizzes?

Comment: You won't be able to have only one SQL query in the background since SQL queries are triggered when querysets are evaluated and you are evaluating two different querysets.